# Computation involving the Hodge star and exterior covariant derivative on an almost complex manifold

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, hodge-theory, almost-complex

Let $M$ be an almost complex manifold of complex dimension $n$. Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle over $M$ with a Hermitian metric $h$. Let $A$ be a Hermitian connection with respect to $h$. Let $d_A$ be the exterior covariant derivative of $A$, and let $F_A$ be the curvature form of $A$. Let $*$ be the Hodge star operator, where it maps $\Omega^{p,q}$ into $\Omega^{n-q,n-p}$. I have several questions about notation and computations using the above objects.

1. I recall reading that one cannot use the usual local basis consisting of $\{ dz^i, d\bar{z}^j \}$ for $\Omega^{p,q}$ because of a lack of complex structure. Is this correct?
2. Do we then get a (nice enough) local basis $e^1, \ldots, e^n, \bar{e}^1, \ldots, \bar{e}^n$ of $T^* M$, for some forms $\{ e^k \}$ and their complex conjugate? Does this make sense, even though we get $2n$ such forms? Or am I misunderstanding how this works?
3. Say $n=2$ for simplicity. If the above is correct, what would $*(e^1 \wedge e^2)$ equal? Would it be $\pm \bar{e}^1 \wedge \bar{e}^2$? Similarly would $*e^1 =\pm e^2 \wedge \bar{e}^1 \wedge \bar{e}^2$? (Modulo some constant factors maybe.)
4. As a concrete example I'd like to work out, I know $F_A$ is a $2$-form with $3$ components $F_A^{2,0}, F_A^{1,1}$, and $F_A^{0,2}$ in $\Omega^{2,0}, \Omega^{1,1}$, and $\Omega^{0,2}$ respectively. What is $* d_A * F_A ^{2,0}$ in terms of the above local basis? We can take $n=2$ for simplicity as well to give a clearer picture. (This form arises in the Yang-Mills functional if you're wondering why I'm interested.)

I've yet to find a set of notes or a textbook that covers these cases (1-3) in detail or similar examples, if you could provide a reference to something like this, that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: All the answers to these questions are in Donaldson & Kronheimer's book "The Geometry of $4$-manifolds".

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thanks for the reference. I've obtained it and perused through it, but I couldn't find anything related to $(p,q)$-forms on almost complex manifolds. Could you perhaps point me to where in the textbook this is covered?

Comment: You are actually correct, that's my mistake. There is an extensive discussion about the $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$ part of the curvature $2$-form of a connection, but it indeed presupposes that you know about these things. So let me correct myself and say that you should go through Huybrechts's "Complex Geometry" (mostly the first chapter is important), and then go to the book I referenced above.